# How to dynamically filter results of Laravel eloquent relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

My model `Parameter` has two fields - `name` and `permission`. If `permission` is blank, every user can access this parameter on related model. If permission is for example set to `see sensitive data`, I want to display the parameter only to users who have the permission. (I'm using spatie permissions).

So if an instance of Equipment had two related parameters - `manufacture date` with blank `permission` and `serial number` with `manage equipment` permission, basic user should only see the first permission in view `Equipment/Show`.

I tried to do this in the eloquent function on `Equipment.php` class, but both my tries failed.

first try:

```
public function params(): MorphToMany
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Parameter::class, 'parameterable')
        ->withPivot('value', 'note')->filter(function ($p) {
            if (!$p->permission || auth()->user()->can($p->permission)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
}
```

second try:

```
public function params(): MorphToMany
{
    $permissions = PermissionService::getAllUserPermissionsArray();

    return $this->morphToMany(Parameter::class, 'parameterable')
        ->withPivot('value', 'note')->whereHas('permission', function ($q) use ($permissions) {
            $q->whereIn('name', $permissions);
        });
}
```

how should i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, i was overthinking it.

```
public function params(): MorphToMany
{
    $permissions = PermissionService::getAllUserPermissionsArray();

    return $this->morphToMany(Parameter::class, 'parameterable')
        ->withPivot('value', 'note')
        ->where('permission', null)
        ->orWhereIn('permission', $permissions);
}
```

**EDIT:**
if someone will be using this post as a reference in the future, **the above answer is incorrect**. `orWhereIn` invalidates the model relation.
this is the correct code in my case:

```
public function params(): MorphToMany
{
    $permissions = PermissionService::getAllUserPermissionsArray();

    return $this->morphToMany(Parameter::class, 'parameterable')
        ->withPivot('value', 'note')
        ->where(function ($q) use ($permissions) {
            $q->where('permission', null)
                ->orWhereIn('permission', $permissions);
        });
}
```